# Error when adding Machine Learning Service to Studio Project

Tags: watson-studio

Error message is:

> Error while selecting instance:Unexpected response code: 500 (Missing >required properties for credentials: access_key)

Looks like the new instances of the  Machine Learning service don't have an access_key field in the credentials anymore but Watson Studio is expecting that field to be there